# Unable to get values from view to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

My view for the new form is

```
<h1>Add Form 3C </h1>
<%= form_for([@basiccase, @form3c]) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :date_of_investigation %>
        <%= f.date_select :date_of_investigation, {:include_blank => true, :default => nil} %>
        </div>
 <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Add Form" %>
     </div>

<% end %>
```

My controller for new and create are

```
def new
    @title = "New Form 3C"
    @basiccase = Basiccase.find_by_id(params[:basiccase_id])
    @form3c = @basiccase.build_form3_c
  end

  def create
    @basiccase = Basiccase.find_by_id(params[:basiccase_id])
    @form3c = @basiccase.build_form3_c(params[:form3c])
             if @form3c.save
            flash[:success] = "Form created!"
            redirect_to current_user
          else
            flash[:warning] ="Failed to create a Form"
            render 'users/show'
          end
  end
```

I'm unable to get the value of params[:form3c] into the the create controller.  when I tried to check puts params[:form3c] it is showing blank. Can Any on help me where i'm wrong

Comment: Have you tried `params[:form3_c]` instead? Look at your development.log file and you should see the full output of the actual params hash whenever you submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A params key will be based on your class name. Rails expects class names to be mixed case (e.g. BasicCase) and creates the param key by lowercasing and separating the words with an underscore.

You can check this in a Rails console using #underscore:

```
1.9.2p290 :001 > "BasicCase".underscore
 => "basic_case"
```

I imagine you have named  your class Form3C which becomes form3_c as Dylan suggested.

You may want to consider renaming both your models to BasicCase and Form3c which should give you params basic_case_id and form3c.

Comment: As Dylan suggested params[:form3_c] worked. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Check your console or development.log, just after click on "Add Form" .

Not sure about exact, but You will find parameter something like :

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"Γ£ô", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "basiccase"=>{"form3c" => {"email"=>"asdsa", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}}}
```

Then use params[:basiccase][:form3c]